# About calling of dispatch_queue_t and dispatch_sync

Tags: iphone, ios, grand-central-dispatch

Why the code `if (dispatch_get_current_queue() == socketQueue)` is needed? why can't we just use `dispatch_sync(socketQueue, block)` directly???

Thanks in advance!

```
- (BOOL)isConnected
{
__block BOOL result = NO;

dispatch_block_t block = ^{
    result = (flags & kConnected) ? YES : NO;
};

if (dispatch_get_current_queue() == socketQueue)
    block();
else
    dispatch_sync(socketQueue, block);

return result;
}
```

BTW, the code is from [XMPPFramework](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot call `dispatch_sync` to schedule blocks on the current serial queue since this will deadlock. Dispatch_sync waits until the block finished executing, but it will never start to run before the current block finished running.

Comment: Hi Sven, see you again.
a little bit unclear. What about dispatch_async, if the block changed a __block value, how could it be async???